# merging content of two tables without duplicating content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two identical SQL Server tables (`SOURCE` and `DESTINATION`) with lots a columns in each.  I want to insert into table `DESTINATION` rows from table `SOURCE` that do not already exist in table `DESTINATION`.  I define equality between the two rows if all columns match except for the timestamp, a count column, and the integer primary key. So I want to insert into `DESTINATION` all rows in `SOURCE` that dont already exist in `DESTINATION`ignoring count, timestamp, and the primary key columns.

How do I do this?

Thanks for all the contributions! I chose to use the Merge command since it is structured to allow for updates and inserts in one statement and I needed to do the update separately.

this is the code that worked:

```
Merge 
into DESTINATION as D
using  SOURCE as S
on (    
D.Col1 = S.Col1
and D.Col2 = S.Col2
and D.Col3 = S.Col3
)
WHEN MATCHED
 THEN UPDATE SET D.Count = S.Count
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT (Col1, Col2, Col3, Count, timestamp)
        VALUES (S.Col1, S.Col2, S.Col3, S.Count, S.timestamp);
```

note: when I wrote this question first I called the tables `AAA` and `BBB`. I edited and changed the names of `AAA` to `SOURCE` AND `BBB` to  `DESTINATION` for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `Select` statement for this purpose since Sql Server 2008 is obsolete instead of `Select` You can use `Merge` statement :

ref:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2007/09/20/Example-of-MERGE-in-SQL-Server-2008.aspx

Comment: Great answer! I wasn't aware of MERGE, but I'm still using 2005 (for a few more weeks), I'll definitely be using it in the future.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use it. the example in the documentation requires you to look through the elements in the AAA table. I think using the right select should avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO BBB(id, timestamp, mycount, col1, col2, col3, etc.)
SELECT id, timestamp, mycount, col1, col2, col3, etc.
   FROM AAA
   WHERE
       NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM BBB oldb WHERE
          oldb.col1 = AAA.col1
          AND oldb.col2 = AAA.col2
          AND oldb.col3 = AAA.col3
       )
```

Add columns as needed to the `NOT EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using good ol'-fashioned `LEFT JOIN` -- note in the example below, only the first row of BBB is inserted into AAA, because only it has no matching row in AAA.  You'd replace `col1` and `col2` with the actual columns of the tables.

```
> select * from AAA;
+---------------------+------+------+
| timestamp           | col1 | col2 |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2012-03-17 08:17:22 |    1 |    1 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:27 |    1 |    2 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:30 |    1 |    3 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:32 |    1 |    4 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:49 |    2 |    2 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:52 |    2 |    3 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:54 |    2 |    4 |
+---------------------+------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> select * from BBB;
+---------------------+------+------+
| timestamp           | col1 | col2 |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2012-03-17 08:18:16 |    2 |    1 |
| 2012-03-17 08:18:18 |    2 |    2 |
| 2012-03-17 08:18:20 |    2 |    3 |
+---------------------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

> INSERT INTO AAA
  SELECT BBB.* FROM BBB
  LEFT JOIN AAA
  USING(col1,col2)
  WHERE AAA.timestamp IS NULL;

> select * from AAA;
+---------------------+------+------+
| timestamp           | col1 | col2 |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2012-03-17 08:17:22 |    1 |    1 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:27 |    1 |    2 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:30 |    1 |    3 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:32 |    1 |    4 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:49 |    2 |    2 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:52 |    2 |    3 |
| 2012-03-17 08:17:54 |    2 |    4 |
| 2012-03-17 08:18:16 |    2 |    1 |
+---------------------+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: USING() is not supported in MSSQL. IIRC, it's a feature of MySQL. But I do like your join method, the syntax is less verbose but cleaner than a correlated subquery.

Comment: @richardtallent could you use ON() rather than USING() in MSSQL?